# PSP emulator that works with 13.04?

Tags: emulation

Do you guys know any PSP emulator (like PPSSPP or JPCSP in Windows) which can be run on 13.04?

If it's not automaticaly configured, please give me step by step configuration to get it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** For those that don't mind adding PPA's, packages are now available [here](https://launchpad.net/~ppsspp/+archive/ubuntu/stable) for 14.04 & 14.10

PPSSPP has a Linux version. The instructions provided only work with the 64 bit version and you have to build the 32bit version yourself, although there is a promise that a .deb for Ubuntu/Debian users is on the way

Download the tar.gz from [here](http://www.ppsspp.org/downloads.html)

Extract to a place of your choice
You can now launch the application by double clicking the executable.

[image]

[image]

To create a launcher and make it searchable from the dash:

If you don't already have it installed then open Software Centre, search for and install 'Main Menu'

Open 'Main Menu' from the dash

[image]

Select a category where you would like to place your application (for this purpose I have selected 'games')

Click on new item, give your launcher a name i.e PPSSPP then in the command box click browse, navigate to the executable you have for PPSSPP, click open

At this point you can just click OK and your launcher will be created, however there is also the option to to give your launcher an icon (unfortunately no icons are included in the download)

To change the icon click on the 'springboard like logo to the left

[image]

you will then be able to select a logo from file or if you have your own navigate to that and select.
If you don't choose a different icon it will just default to the springboard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your information! I downloaded it but I can't find PPSSPPSDL just like in your picture. The tar.gz files only contain PPSSPPHeadless, assets folder, and a text files.

Comment: Nope. double clicking it doesnt do anything, if im trying to run ./PPSSPPHeadless in terminal it ask to include an elf file, so I run ./PPSSPPHeadless cube.elf (test image that available in the website), and it just hang there, no additional line on terminal or any graphical windows created, but it consuming 20% of my CPU until I ctrl-c it. I tried to leave it for 20 minutes, but still no luck.

Comment: Seems like the hard work has been done for you in the 64bit version but not the 32. You have to build that yourself although they are promising a .deb for Ubuntu users soon. You may want to check http://forums.ppsspp.org/showthread.php?tid=1298 for help

Comment: Well I guess that's that. I will build it following your link then. I'll post it soon.

Comment: It works man, at least for test images (the cube.elf), thanks! I'll try with another images once I have it. If you have the time please write an answer.

Comment: Um one more question, how do I include PPSSPPSDL to be searchable on Unity Dash?

Comment: @Nur Please see edit

Answer (score 2):

JPCSP is also available for Linux

Download 32 bit from [here](http://rapidgator.net/file/442506869e514ee9118a7ed5800cdf1f/jpcsp-r3168-linux-x86-32.7z.html)

64bit from [here](http://rapidgator.net/file/cbf5506d55dfc8169fca440ba17146c3/jpcsp-r3168-linux-x86-64.7z.html)

Once extracted you will need to make start-linux.sh executable. Right click on the file and choose Properties open the permissions tab and check the 'Allow executing file as program`box, click Close.

[image]

You can now run the program by double clicking start-linux.sh

[image]

PSPong came with the download, I'm guessing to test with.

Comment: I can't download from rapidgator (seems like my ISP blocking it), do you have another link?

Comment: http://buildbot.orphis.net/jpcsp/ I tested revision 3175 64bit worked well